# Why are Java objects 8-byte aligned instead of 4-byte aligned

Tags: java

I was using Jol to look at the memory layout of the object and found an 8-byte alignment field in the object field. What bothered me was that I didn't understand why the 8-byte alignment was not 4-byte

Comment: ...Because there are atomic types that are 8 bytes in size? Better yet: why did you expect 4-byte alignment? Why not any other number?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that you are [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to try to do some research before asking here. [Literally copying and pasting your question title into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Why+are+Java+objects+8-byte+aligned+instead+of+4-byte+aligned) is enough to get some useful information. Also, "why" questions are usually a poor fit for Stack Overflow; design decisions are best justified by *those who made them*.

Comment: Other alignment is also possible, 4 bytes is just an example, my understanding is that the CPU cache line size is 64 bytes, so it is ok to set to 4 bytes for ease of reading, even 2 bytes, 8 bytes alignment will even waste memory?

Comment: So if you freely acknowledge that other alignments are possible, why does it "bother" you that they chose 8 rather than 4, 2 or some other value?  After all, they did have to make a choice.

Answer (score 1):

8-byte pointers on 64bit-systems and 8byte-java-object alignment actually don't have much to do with each other.

First of all: **The alignment does not have to be 8 bytes**, it is configurable with the jvm-option `-XX:ObjectAlignmentInBytes`. 8 is the default, and 8 is the minimum. There are good reasons for this default and this minimum, as we will see later.

Second: The size of a pointer does not decide on alignment. A 64-bit pointer can address single bytes, just like a 32bit pointer can. And in languages like `C` it *is* typical to use 64-bit-pointers, even though the compiler does not force 8-byte alignment on all objects.

---

**So why is 8-bytes the default alignment of objects?** Because 64-bit-java uses only 32-bits for an object reference. 32-bit-pointers can only reference 2<sup>32</sup> memory locations, which is 4GB if you try to reference every byte. But if you only reference every eigth byte, those 2<sup>32</sup> memory locations become 32GB of memory, which is much more acceptable.

If you need more than 32GB of memory, it may make sense to set the object alignment higher than 8, to another power of 2, and maybe the default will be raised to 16 at some point in the future. This will waste more space in your application but increase the amount of total space java-objects can occupy. Note how this tradeoff is independent of CPU-register-sizes, cachelines, or considerations about atomic instructions. It is about how much memory an application needs.

Read more about these so-called *compressed ordinary object pointers (COOPS)* here:
https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-compressed-oops

---

Now, **why is 8-bytes the minimum alignment of objects?**

In languages like `C`, the compiler may choose any alignment for a data structure (or a programmer can specify something). It is generally different for each 'class' (struct). Aligning eg a 2-byte struct to 8-bytes would waste 6 bytes, unacceptable in many applications where `C` is used.

But you can not have a 2-byte-class in java, because every instance of every object has an object header. The size of that header depends on implementation, but it is not nothing: [jol](https://openjdk.org/projects/code-tools/jol/) shows me 12-byte headers on 64-bit implementations. Any fields that your class has come on top of that. The relative space wasted by aligning to 8 bytes can therefore never be as bad as in the `C`-example above.

But that just explains why aligning to 8-bytes is 'not so bad', not why it is actually helpful. We need to go deeper.

What is in these 12-byte-headers?
8 bytes are the *mark word*, the remaining 4 bytes are the *class word*. See here: https://shipilev.net/jvm/objects-inside-out/
The class word works like an object reference because it is more or less a pointer to the class of the object.

The mark word is more interesting. It contains different kinds of stuff (gc-stuff, hashcode, locking) packed into 64-bits of memory, the C++-code for openjdk is [here](https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk/jdk/file/19afeaa0fdbe/src/hotspot/share/oops/markWord.hpp#l33). With this kind of low-level stuff, alignment actually does become important because the assembler-code is simpler if alignment can be assumed. Now, the detailed tradeoffs of packing memory versus using more instructions may be use-case specific. But what C/C++-compilers generally do when they encounter 8-byte-types is align them to 8-byte-boundaries, *even if that means wasting space*.

Example:

```
#include<cstdint>
#include<iostream>
struct sample {
    uint32_t a;
    uint64_t field;
};

int main() {
    // prints 16, not 12, with any compiler I tried
    std::cout << sizeof(sample) << std::endl;
}
```

The size of sample could be 12, but 4 bytes of waste are added just to make `field` more CPU-friendly. (one thing to note here is that the C and C++-standards prevent the compiler from reordering the struct-members).

So it is probably a good performance-choice to have the mark-word be aligned to 8 bytes. Since every java-object starts with a mark-word, they too need to be aligned to 8 bytes.

Answer (score -1):

I think I have found the answer. The size of a pointer to a CPU address is 8 bytes. If an object is not aligned to 8 bytes, then it may pollute the cache line

Comment: Nope.  The hardware would cope with that just fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).